# What is the alternate for elastic river-mongodb plugin, supported by elasticsearch 2.2.0?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Need to replace the river-mongodb plugin as we are upgrading the elastic search. As the river-mongodb is outdated, need your help in figuring out the alternate for that. 
We need to index the entire mongodb collection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two alternatives that I know of:

1. Using [Mongo connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki)
2. Using Logstash with the community-supported [mongodb input plugin](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb)

The advantage of 1 over 2 is that it is an official connector from the MongoDB folks, but if you're more into Logstash then the second alternative might better suit you.

**UPDATE**

Another one would be [mongolastic](https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongolastic) which provides two-way synchs between MongoDB and Elasticsearch

**UPDATE2**

[mongo-connector](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector) is not currently supported by MongoDB, Inc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. from community supported perspective, are there any other plugins available ?

Comment: There's [another one](https://github.com/helaili/MongoDBLogstashPlugin) but it doesn't seem very active.

Comment: Hey @Val. how about [this one] (https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic) ? any idea ?

Comment: That would be another option, indeed, but that adds another abstraction layer on top of your existing MongoDB code, which might be desired or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Val for providing yet another option. Much appreciated. I need to finalize on the approach in couple of days. I am currently verifying all the options. Thanks for giving an extended help.

Comment: Hi Val, I tried mongelastic, but to index collection of 30,000 records, it has taken around 6 hours. Am i missing anything, or generally it takes this much time?

Comment: Hi, if you're referring to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734662/mongolastic-is-taking-long-time-to-index-a-collection), I'm not sure why it takes that much time. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 6):

Here I found another good option to migrate your MongoDB data to Elasticsearch.
A go daemon that syncs mongodb to elasticsearch in realtime.
Its the Monstache. Its available at :  [Monstache](https://rwynn.github.io/monstache-site/)

Below the initial setp to configure and use it.

Step 1:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --replSet test
```

Step 2 :

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.2
Server has startup warnings:
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY>
```

Step 3 : Verify the replication.

```
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY> rs.status();
{
        "set" : "test",
        "date" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:39:00.380Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(2),
        "syncingTo" : "",
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                }
        },
        "lastStableCheckpointTimestamp" : Timestamp(1547811517, 1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "localhost:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 736,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(2)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:38:57Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1547810805, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:26:45Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY>
```

Step 4.
    Download the "https://github.com/rwynn/monstache/releases".
    Unzip the download and adjust your PATH variable to include the path to the folder for your platform.
    GO to cmd and type `"monstache -v"`
    # 4.13.1
    Monstache uses the TOML format for its configuration. Configure the file for migration named config.toml

Step 5.

My config.toml -->

```
mongo-url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?replicaSet=test"
elasticsearch-urls = ["http://localhost:9200"]

direct-read-namespaces = [ "admin.users" ]

gzip = true
stats = true
index-stats = true

elasticsearch-max-conns = 4
elasticsearch-max-seconds = 5
elasticsearch-max-bytes = 8000000 

dropped-collections = false
dropped-databases = false

resume = true
resume-write-unsafe = true
resume-name = "default"
index-files = false
file-highlighting = false
verbose = true
exit-after-direct-reads = false

index-as-update=true
index-oplog-time=true
```

Step 6.

```
D:\15-1-19>monstache -f config.toml
```

[image: Monstache Running...]

[image: Confirm Migrated Data at Elasticsearch]

[image: Add Record at Mongo]

[image: Monstache Captured the event and migrate the data to elasticsearch]