# How i can transfer the data from mongoDB to a elasticSearch 2.2.0?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, etl

Well i need transport the data from mongoDB to elastticSearch but I don't can use the river plugins because are deprecated.

What is the best way for do this assignment?

Comment: You might want to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374216/what-is-the-alternate-for-elastic-river-mongodb-plugin-supported-by-elasticsear/35375990#35375990

Answer (score 1):

Dump your mongodb database using the mongodump utility. You should then be able to directly import the dump file into elasticsearch using their utility for doing so, which is explained here.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html

Answer (score 1):

Here I found another good option to migrate your MongoDB data to Elasticsearch.
a go daemon that syncs mongodb to elasticsearch in realtime.
Its the Monstache. Its available at :  https://rwynn.github.io/monstache-site/

Below the initial setp to configure and use it.

Step 1:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --replSet test
```

Step 2 :

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.2
Server has startup warnings:
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-01-18T16:56:44.931+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY>
```

Step 3 : Verify the replication.

```
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY> rs.status();
{
        "set" : "test",
        "date" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:39:00.380Z"),
        "myState" : 1,
        "term" : NumberLong(2),
        "syncingTo" : "",
        "syncSourceHost" : "",
        "syncSourceId" : -1,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(2)
                }
        },
        "lastStableCheckpointTimestamp" : Timestamp(1547811517, 1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "localhost:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 1,
                        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                        "uptime" : 736,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(2)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:38:57Z"),
                        "syncingTo" : "",
                        "syncSourceHost" : "",
                        "syncSourceId" : -1,
                        "infoMessage" : "",
                        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1547810805, 1),
                        "electionDate" : ISODate("2019-01-18T11:26:45Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 1,
                        "self" : true,
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1547811537, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
MongoDB Enterprise test:PRIMARY>
```

Step 4.
    Download the "https://github.com/rwynn/monstache/releases".
    Unzip the download and adjust your PATH variable to include the path to the folder for your platform.
    GO to cmd and type `"monstache -v"`
    # 4.13.1
    Monstache uses the TOML format for its configuration. Configure the file for migration named config.toml

Step 5.

My config.toml -->

```
mongo-url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?replicaSet=test"
elasticsearch-urls = ["http://localhost:9200"]

direct-read-namespaces = [ "admin.users" ]

gzip = true
stats = true
index-stats = true

elasticsearch-max-conns = 4
elasticsearch-max-seconds = 5
elasticsearch-max-bytes = 8000000 

dropped-collections = false
dropped-databases = false

resume = true
resume-write-unsafe = true
resume-name = "default"
index-files = false
file-highlighting = false
verbose = true
exit-after-direct-reads = false

index-as-update=true
index-oplog-time=true
```

Step 6.

```
D:\15-1-19>monstache -f config.toml
```

Answer (score 0):

After many trials and failures with various tools such as Monstache, Apache NiFi, and Logstash, I found a great tool namely [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/) which is very user-friendly and has good performance in syncing MongoDB database into a web-based application that lets you visualize and analyze your data.