# mongolastic is taking long time to index a collection

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I am using [mongolastic](https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongolastic), to index a collection in elasticsearch.

It took around 6 hours to index a collection having 30,000 documents. Is there a way we can increase the efficiency?

Also, it was noted that the indexing was done in batch (of 200), can we increase this limit too?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: The same code as it is in  https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongolastic. i even downloaded the code and build a executable jar and tried.

Comment: could you please try the latest version of the tool, and give your feedback on the tool's page? thanks @user1819071

Comment: sure.. I will try it today and let you know @Hakan. ..

Comment: wow. great the time has reduced significantly. Thanks a lot @Hakan. Thanks again

Comment: you're welcome @user1819071, thank you for using the tool and If you have any suggestions/ideas , just open an issue on github, we can improve it.

Comment: @Hakan sorry for stalking you here, but could u have a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083369/mongodb-elasticsearch-mongolastic-error

Answer (score 0):

As for the limit of the batch size - this is taken from the link you provided yourself:

> 6. Override the default batch size which is normally 200. (Optional)

```
batch: <number>         (6)
```