# MongoDB elasticsearch mongolastic error

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

So I'm trying to transfer from mongodb to elasticsearch. However I keep getting stuck on the errors I'm getting, hope someone can help me out here.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
0 [main] INFO com.kodcu.config.FileConfiguration  - 
Config Output:
{elastic=Elastic{host='localhost', port=9300, dateFormat=null, longToString=false}, misc=Misc{batch=200, direction='me', dindex=Namespace{as='yapdns', name='yapdns'}, ctype=Namespace{as='dnsinfo', name='dnsinfo'}, dropDataset=true}, mongo=Mongo{host='localhost', port=27017, query='{}', auth=com.kodcu.config.yml.Auth@5577140b}}

165 [main] INFO org.elasticsearch.plugins  - [Iron Man 2020] modules [], plugins [], sites []
176 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [force_merge], type [fixed], size [1], queue_size [null]
182 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [percolate], type [fixed], size [2], queue_size [1k]
192 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [fetch_shard_started], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
192 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [listener], type [fixed], size [1], queue_size [null]
192 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [index], type [fixed], size [2], queue_size [200]
193 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [refresh], type [scaling], min [1], size [1], keep_alive [5m]
193 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [suggest], type [fixed], size [2], queue_size [1k]
193 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [generic], type [cached], keep_alive [30s]
194 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [warmer], type [scaling], min [1], size [1], keep_alive [5m]
194 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [search], type [fixed], size [4], queue_size [1k]
194 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [flush], type [scaling], min [1], size [1], keep_alive [5m]
194 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [fetch_shard_store], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
194 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [management], type [scaling], min [1], size [5], keep_alive [5m]
194 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [get], type [fixed], size [2], queue_size [1k]
194 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [bulk], type [fixed], size [2], queue_size [50]
195 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool  - [Iron Man 2020] creating thread_pool [snapshot], type [scaling], min [1], size [1], keep_alive [5m]
525 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.common.network  - configuration:

lo
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask:255.0.0.0 scope:host
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen:128 scope:host
        UP LOOPBACK mtu:65536 index:1

ens33
        inet 192.168.79.136 netmask:255.255.255.0 broadcast:192.168.79.255 scope:site
        inet6 fe80::44ac:303c:270a:57cb prefixlen:64 scope:link
        hardware 00:0C:29:31:1C:6E
        UP MULTICAST mtu:1500 index:2

545 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.common.netty  - using gathering [true]
577 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.client.transport  - [Iron Man 2020] node_sampler_interval[5s]
595 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil  - Using select timeout of 500
595 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil  - Epoll-bug workaround enabled = false
616 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.client.transport  - [Iron Man 2020] adding address [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}]
646 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Iron Man 2020] connected to node [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}]
675 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.transport.netty  - [Iron Man 2020] connected to node [{Main Elastic}{OWIZkFPKRa-BpIu4pAjV8w}{127.0.0.1}{localhost/127.0.0.1:9300}{master=true}]
721 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster  - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='5000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
722 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster  - Adding discovered server localhost:27017 to client view of cluster
767 [main] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster  - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]
789 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster  - No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primaryPreferred} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 5000 ms before timing out
884 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:1}
885 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster  - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=PLAIN, userName='admin', source='yapdns', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59: 'no such cmd: saslStart' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: saslStart", "code" : 59, "bad cmd" : { "saslStart" : 1, "mechanism" : "PLAIN", "payload" : { "$binary" : "YWRtaW4AYWRtaW4AYWRtaW4xMjM=", "$type" : "0" } } }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:45)
    ... 5 more
891 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster  - Updating cluster description to  {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=PLAIN, userName='admin', source='yapdns', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59: 'no such cmd: saslStart' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: saslStart", "code" : 59, "bad cmd" : { "saslStart" : 1, "mechanism" : "PLAIN", "payload" : { "$binary" : "YWRtaW4AYWRtaW4AYWRtaW4xMjM=", "$type" : "0" } } }}}]
1396 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:2}
1901 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:3}
2406 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:4}
2910 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:5}
3418 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:6}
3922 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:7}
4427 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:8}
4931 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:9}
5435 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5772bbf5a886531ce72d0726', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection  - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:10}
5791 [main] INFO com.kodcu.main.Mongolastic  - Load duration: 5790ms
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primaryPreferred}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=PLAIN, userName='admin', source='yapdns', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}}, caused by {com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 59: 'no such cmd: saslStart' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "no such cmd: saslStart", "code" : 59, "bad cmd" : { "saslStart" : 1, "mechanism" : "PLAIN", "payload" : { "$binary" : "YWRtaW4AYWRtaW4AYWRtaW4xMjM=", "$type" : "0" } } }}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:201)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CountOperation.execute(CountOperation.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CountOperation.execute(CountOperation.java:53)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:772)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:759)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.count(MongoCollectionImpl.java:185)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.count(MongoCollectionImpl.java:170)
    at com.kodcu.provider.MongoToElasticProvider.getCount(MongoToElasticProvider.java:33)
    at com.kodcu.provider.Provider.transfer(Provider.java:17)
    at com.kodcu.main.Mongolastic.proceedService(Mongolastic.java:61)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at com.kodcu.main.Mongolastic.start(Mongolastic.java:50)
    at com.kodcu.main.Mongolastic.main(Mongolastic.java:38)
```

The config file I created is:

```
misc:
    dindex:
        name: yapdns
        as: yapdns
    ctype:
        name: dnsinfo
        as: dnsinfo
    direction: me
mongo:
    host: localhost
    port: 27017
    auth:
        user: admin
        pwd: "xxxxxx"
        source: yapdns
        mechanism: plain
elastic:
    host: localhost
port: 9300
```

I've tried multiple things and trial and error but I can't seem to find out what these errors are actually saying. If you need more info about what settings I have, please let me know.

Comment: I will give my comments on [GitHub page](https://github.com/ozlerhakan/mongolastic/issues/13)

Comment: Alright cool, sorry for late reply, just saw it indeed.