# how to sync data from mongodb to elastic search with python

Tags: python, mongodb, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am currentlt using Monstache connector for sync MongoDB elastic search. is there any other recommended connector for sync.

Architecture: Angular7 Elastic Search Mongo DB Python Pycharm.

is there any other solution apart from this. https://rwynn.github.io/monstache-site/.

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35375990/4604579

Comment: @val - i have seen that question before ask this. in my case i am using python as server side , mongo-connector is not currently supported by MongoDB, Inc. mongolostic supported for node js , currently using monstache , is there any other solution. elastic river is depricated.